# Email database backup file from application - android

Tags: android, database, email, backup

I have created the backup file for the SQLite Database i have used in my application. All i want is to send this backup file through email. I have implemented the file sending Intent but when they open, it says, you can only send files like (Image, Coarse Location etc.)

```
String pathname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String filename = "/Android/data/<package-name>/databases/hello.db";
File file=new File(pathname, filename);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Database Backup");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey there, database successfully sent.");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));`i.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Your email id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to Security reason, you can't email data from **data** folder, SO before emailing export it to SD card and then send, It should work.

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: i have tried it. But when the gmail app opens, it says invalid file format. It shows this error

<qeglDrvAPI_eglTerminate:2531>: <<<< Reset Blob Cache Funcs >>>>

Comment: yes got the solution. Actually i didn't realized that i was using the pathname as String. While, it should have been in file format. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting text/plain as attachment type probably causes email client to attempt to preview file as text. You should use other MIME type, such as "application/octet-stream", or even "any" mask - "*/*".

Here is an extremely dirty and simple snippet, that works just fine for me:

```java
File dbFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "example.db");
SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "example text");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "database sending example");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(dbFile));
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Comment: yes tried it also. But still not able to send the database file. I have also tried to upload it to google drive. But it also say's unable to upload file.

Comment: Have you used this solution together with one, provided by Ayush Ghosh (e.g. moving to SD card before sharing it from there)? Does logcat output contains anything seemingly useful?

Comment: yes i have used both the solutions. But still not able to send file. Gmail only offers to send files like picture, mp3, location etc. And also the current location of my file is "file:///<folder-name>/<database-name>.db"

Comment: I am not sure, what kind of problems are you facing? By the way, what does `<folder-name>` in your path represent? Is it an absolute path? Does that file exist? Whatever, I have edited the question to contain working snippet, like one I use myself.